# Delete multiple joined records retrieved from search engine in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a search engine that will retrieve specific records from joined tables. The retrieved record will display in a table that includes a hyperlink to allow the user to delete it. When writing the code, I am not sure when using the DELETE FROM query should the WHERE statement indicate the $search variable or the $id variable since it is deleting from both tables by id? I keep getting an error msg that states "invalid argument supplied foreach().  Here is the code below.  Thanks for your assistance.

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$search = $_GET['search'];
$delQuery = "DELETE FROM ac_registration 
    WHERE $choice LIKE '%".$search."%'";

$delQuery = "DELETE FROM ac_studentdemo
    Where ac_registration.id = ac_studentdemo.id";

mysql_query($delQuery, $dbHandle) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db,$dbHandle);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ac_registration, ac_studentdemo";
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbHandle);

$registerArr = array();

while($inRow = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($registerArr, $inRow);
}
mysql_close($dbHandle);
}
echo "<p>Record has been deleted!</p>";
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';

foreach($registerArr[0] as $k=>$col) {
if($k !="ID") {
}
echo'</tr>';
}
foreach($registerArr as $row) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach($row as $key=>$col) {
    if($key != "ID") {
        echo"<td>$col</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td><a href=\"deleteData2.php?ID=$col\">X</a></td>";
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not even parseable (it has unbalanced curly brackets) - `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/sakfa/test.php on line 22`

in 4th line you overwrite query with invalid one.

tidy code up or nobody will help you.